# Prevent the user to submit if no changes have been made to an ant-design form in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have some form, where the user can load data from a data base, edit some fields and submit afterwards. But submission should only be possible, if the user actually made some changes to the form. In case it is still in the state from last submission, the submit button should be disabled.

I tried to use the form.isFieldsTouched method of the documentation:

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-inline-login

But the problem is that once the fields have been "touched", there is no way the form can go back into the untouched state via the submit button. At least, I could not find a way.

```html
<Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item shouldUpdate>
        {() => (
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            disabled={
              !form.isFieldsTouched()
            }
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

I also tried using the form.onFieldsChange method, which sets the "touched" state via the useState-Hook. The submit button then sets the state back to "untouched". But this way, I somehow loose the first keystroke after an "untouched" state, which is quite annoying.

Comment: I've implemented an example here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v7cig1 is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Of course, I have to adjust this code to my much more complex form. I have several tabs with several ant-design forms. To get the entries of all fields I use the concept of uplifting those states to the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false)

const handleChangeForm = () => {
    setState(form.isFieldsTouched())
  }

<Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item>
        {() => (
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            disabled={ !state }
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
</Form>
```